# Why do I get different results when use pool.apply_async and Process.start with multiprocessing.Array in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Here is my code, from id() I know in apply_async copy a new array, but I want to know why this happens and how to change apply_async result same as Process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Pool
import numpy as np
from ctypes import c_ubyte


def f(a):
    print(id(a))
    a[1] = np.uint8(255)
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Array(c_ubyte, np.zeros((4,), dtype=np.uint8), lock=False)
    a_ = np.frombuffer(a, dtype=np.uint8)
    print(id(a_))

    # no modified
    pool = Pool(2)
    res = pool.apply_async(f, (a_,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("after pool")
    print('a:', a[:])

    # modified
    p = Process(target=f, args=(a_,))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print("after Process")
    print('a:', a[:])
```

**Python3.8.12 on Ubuntu20.04.3 with 5.4.0-89-generic**

```
140093177017008
140093105620032
after pool
a: [0, 0, 0, 0]
140093177017008
after Process
a: [0, 255, 0, 0]
```

**Python3.8.8 on Windows10 Enterprise Edition (19043.1320)**

```
3052081498672
2029320041136
after pool
a: [0, 0, 0, 0]
2599805510560
after Process
a: [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Please post the results you're getting, and what you were expecting to get. "why is a copy made?" because processes don't share memory, and a copy must be made because there's no way to access the same actual object.

Comment: I'm getting: `after pool, a: [0, 0, 0, 0]` and `after Process, a: [0, 0, 0, 0]`. Seems exactly the same answer to me. Should it be different? If so, post full script code so we can see it for our selves.